# How can i change row height of a GridView at runtime

Tags: android, gridview, height

Is there a way to change row height of a GridView? I need to do this via code (not xml). I get some images from a webservice to create the gridView. Row height must match the height of the first image i get.

I need to do the same with the width, but i saw that there's a method called "setColumnWidth". Can't find something similar for the row height.